# Can I test for different moderation effects using several regression models or do they have to be included in one?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

Let's say I have 8 independent variables A-H which I want to test for significance regarding each of their influences on the dependent variable Z. Now let's say that I additionally suspect moderation effects between variable A and DEF (so A with D, A with E, A with F) as well as between variable B and DEF. Would I then have to test all this with one large regression model with 8 main effects and 6 interaction effects? Given that I have a really small sample size of 26, such an approach seems senseless, right?

Could I, however test for significance of the main effects in one model, then for the significance of the interactions between A and DEF (which would then be 4 main effects and 3 interaction terms) and then in a third model for the interaction between B and DEF?

Or could I even break it down to one model per interaction: One for interaction between A and D, one for A and C and so on...?

I mean would any of those approaches be strictly wrong?

Comment: I am afraid the only honest answer is that you need to collect more data. Running a linear regression with eight predictor variables and 26 observations is very optimistic even before you start adding interaction terms.

Comment: thanks!
and it would not make a difference whether I run one multiple regression with 8 regressors or 8 linear regressions with each of the regressors seperately, right? I wouldn't find a significant effect for the linear regression with regressor A but no main effect for A in the multiple regression, or would that be possible?